# How do I manage DNS names for a Keycloak deployment on a local docker compose environment?

Tags: docker, keycloak

I have a docker compose with several services:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ...

  auth-service:
    image: mykeycloakimage:latest
    ...

  rest-service:
    image: myrestserviceimage:latest
    ...

  web-ui:
    image: mywebuiimage:latest
    ...

  proxy-service:
    image: mynginximage:latest
    ...
```

I also have `/etc/hosts` edited on my workstation so everything points to localhost:

```
127.0.0.1 auth-service.mylocal.com
127.0.0.1 rest-api.mylocal.com
127.0.0.1 web-ui.mylocal.com
```

The web-ui container is an Angular app, secured with keycloak-angular 9.1.0.  This is working fine - I hit a restricted page, login, and get a JWT bearer token back.  This is then passed back to my REST service with the header `Authorization: bearer [token]`.

The problem then comes however when the REST service (a Spring Boot backend secured with keycloak-spring-boot-starter) goes to authenticate that bearer token.  To match the resource/realm, it needs to reach out to `auth-service.mylocal.com`, but that only exists in the host's `/etc/hosts` file.

I've tried:

- Using just `auth-service` in the REST authentication - but then this won't match the incoming bearer token.
- Using just `auth-service` in the /etc/hosts file - but then I can't share cookies between the web-ui and rest-service containers, which I need to do.
- Using `auth-service.mylocal.com` everywhere - the REST service doesn't natively know what this is, and when it reaches out to it's DNS provider it bypasses the host's /etc/host settings, so it can't find this domain name.
- Using extra hosts on the REST container - this doesn't really work, because it's inside the docker compose context, and if I set it to 127.0.0.1 it would point at the local container, not the host.
- I think I can't use host networking because I'm on macos.

So... How are people setting this up for local testing/development?  How do you manage the auth token in an Angular app (or other front end), pass that back to a back end service, and have the back end service use the token - all from inside a local docker compose (or swarm or probably k8) context?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post what I arrived at here:

#1 - Use network aliases in the compose file.  So something of the form:

```
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - auth-service.mylocal.com
```

This will tell anything on the backend network to route auth-service.mylocal.com to this service.

#2 - Place the network alias on the proxy server, not the actual auth service.  Assuming the auth service isn't running on port 80, you'll still want nginx to do the mapping from 80->8080 or whatever (plus whatever other voodoo you have nginx doing).

#3 - Adjust the proxy service and docker compose so nginx is listening (at least for auth service requests) on port 80.